# how to append the button to each <li> tag in javascript using forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I want to append the `button` tag to each of the 6 `li` tags using a `forEach` loop but after running the below code I am only getting a `button` tag on the 6th (last) `li` tag. Please help and let me what I am doing wrong.

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('delete'));
var spam = document.createElement('spam');
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

li.forEach(function(i) {
  i.appendChild(button);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
  <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
  <button id="enter" width='50px'>Enter</button>
  <ul>
    <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
    <li>Jello</li>
    <li>Spinach</li>
    <li>Rice</li>
    <li>Birthday Cake</li>
    <li>Candles</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Shubh said you need to move the createElement inside the foreach loop. and create a new button element each time and append it to the li elements.
because the variable button that you created at the beginnig is refering to the created element. each iteration you are just assigning it to another li node.
so:

```
li.forEach(function(item){ 
      var button=document.createElement('button');
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('delete'));
  item.appendChild(button);
   });
```

Answer (score 4):

Just move `document.createElement('button')`in  `forEach Loop` of yours

```js
var spam = document.createElement('spam');
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

li.forEach(function(i) {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('delete'));
  i.appendChild(button);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
  <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
  <button id="enter" width='50px'>Enter</button>
  <ul>
    <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
    <li>Jello</li>
    <li>Spinach</li>
    <li>Rice</li>
    <li>Birthday Cake</li>
    <li>Candles</li>
  </ul>

</body>
```